# Excel - any way to auto hide empty columns when filtering rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am working with data that's imported from a NOSQL database.

Sometimes I get worksheets with 1000 columns and up where most of the cells have no data in them.

I am looking for a way that when I filter the data and show only specific rows, all the columns for the visible rows which have no data at all will hide automatically.

This way, I will not have to horizontally scroll hundreds of empty columns looking for information.

If you have a solution for this need, I will be grateful.

Thanks,

Hanan Cohen

Comment: You could do it with a macro, but I suppose it would have slow performance. Any chance to change the format you receive? I suppose it's already kind of cross table / pivot. If you could get the row data, than you could filter your data with a pivot table in Excel efficiently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will hide columns if only the header cell is filled:

```
Sub KolumnHider()
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim i As Long, r As Range

    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    For i = 1 To 1000
        Set r = Cells(1, i).EntireColumn
        If wf.CountA(r) < 2 Then r.Hidden = True
    Next i
End Sub
```

If there are no column headers, then make the ***2*** into a ***1***.

Comment: Thanks! It didn't work due to the fact that CountA() counts cells regardless if they are visible or not. After some searching, I replaced CountA(r) with Subtotal(3,r) and it worked.

Comment: @HananCohen  That is a great solution! ........ Good job!

Answer (score 2):

*This VBA code will hide all blank columns whether or not they have a header.*

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

  Dim rng As Range
  Dim nLastRow As Long
  Dim nLastColumn As Integer
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim HideIt As Boolean
  Dim j As Long

  Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  nLastRow = rng.Rows.Count + rng.Row - 1
  nLastColumn = rng.Columns.Count + rng.Column - 1

  For i = 1 To nLastColumn
     HideIt = True

  For j = 2 To nLastRow

    If Cells(j, i).Value <> "" Then
      HideIt = False
    End If
  Next

    If HideIt = True Then
      Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
  Next

End Sub
```

**Notes:**

- If you are using a standard filter command from the menu to filter
  the records, run this code first and then filter.
- If you are using VBA code to filter the records, call this subroutine
  first within your code.  In that case, it would be better to replace
  "CommandButton1_Click" with some other name, perhaps "Private Sub
  HideBlankColumn()".

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't make it to work. The code by @garys-student did the job with a small correction.

Comment: I'm surprised,, it's working properly, I always test the solution then upload here as answer. Please write me any Error if you have received, if you feel I can load the screen shot also.

Comment: @HananCohen,, check now I've uploaded the screen shot, where you can easily find both situations.

Comment: If you can instruct me how to add the button and run the script I would be grateful.

Comment: Sure,, first click Developer button from Ribbon, you find Design Mode click it. Left to it has Insert, click and you find ActiveX Controls. The Top left is command button Icon, Select & insert any where in sheet you like. When you move mouse over it you find Crossbar then double click the button, now the VB Editor window will open & you find Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

End Sub.

In between Copy & Paste this code, save and return to Sheet, turn off Design mode and hit the button to RUN the code.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the Rajesh S code to take care of applied filters, to exit from the internal loop as soon as possible and to unhide columns if applied filters changes the visible rows. Run HydeEmptyColumns after filtering.

```
Public Sub HydeEmptyColumns()

  Dim rng As Range
  Dim nLastRow As Long
  Dim nLastColumn As Integer
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim HideIt As Boolean
  Dim j As Long

  Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  nLastRow = rng.Rows.Count + rng.row - 1
  nLastColumn = rng.Columns.Count + rng.Column - 1

  For i = 1 To nLastColumn
    HideIt = True

    For j = 2 To nLastRow
      If Not Rows(j).Hidden Then
        If Cells(j, i).Value <> "" Then
          HideIt = False
          Exit For
        End If
      End If
    Next

    Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = HideIt
  Next

End Sub
```