# Amend VBA code to hide empty columns in whole workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I found the below code in this thread ([Excel - any way to auto hide empty columns when filtering rows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1301266/excel-any-way-to-auto-hide-empty-columns-when-filtering-rows)) which hides columns with only a header in them but no data. It works fine for what I'm doing, but it only does one worksheet, whereas I need it to do the whole workbook.

Hopefully that's an easy change, but I'm new to this - would someone be kind enough to amend the below, please?

```
Sub KolumnHider()
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Dim i As Long, r As Range

Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
For i = 1 To 1000
    Set r = Cells(1, i).EntireColumn
    If wf.CountA(r) < 2 Then r.Hidden = True
Next i
End Sub
```

Thanks, Ewan

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of

```
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Dim i As Long, r As Range
Dim sh as Worksheet

Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
For Each sh in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For i = 1 To 1000
        Set r = sh.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn
        If wf.CountA(r) < 2 Then r.Hidden = True
    Next i
Next
```

Additionally, I would replace the "1000" in that code by

```
 sh.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
```

to make the code loop over the exact number of columns required, not just 1000, which may be too many or too few.

Comment: Thanks very much - that's great. Was going to replace the 1000 with a lower number, but that code will make it much neater. Much appreciated.